# In any base $b$, $\forall n\in\mathbb{N}$ built from digits $\{1,2\}$, if you tally distinct digits in those $n^2$, finitely many have $\leq b/2$

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-number-theory, decimal-expansion

E.g. let $f(n)$ be the $n$th largest natural number consisting of only digits $\{1,2\}$, written in base-10.

It appears from early data that for $1\leq k \leq 9$, there is a maximum $n$ such that the number of distinct digits in the base-10 value of $f(n)^2$ is $k$ or fewer.

It looks like the first several results are:

$$
\begin{array}{|l|l|l|l|}
k & n & f(n) & f(n)^2 & \textrm{digits in }f(n)^2\\\hline
1 & 2 & 2 & 4 & \{4\} \\\hline
2 & 12 & 212 & 44944 & \{4,9\} \\\hline
3 & 52 & 21212 & 449948944 & \{4,8,9\} \\\hline
4 & 114 & 221122 & 48894938884 & \{3,4,8,9\} \\\hline
5 & 7336 & 221121212112 & 48894590445880095500544 & \{0,4,5,8,9\}
\end{array}
$$

I am curious whether my conjecture below can be proven true or false, (or failing that, 'likely to be true/false' is acceptable with reasoning).

---

##### Update

After a bunch of simulation, I conjecture that given any radix $r>2$ and sufficiently large $c$, then of all terms $n>c$ in base $r$ which consist only of digits in $\{1,2\}$, the count of distinct digits appearing in $n^2$ must be in the interval $$\left[\left\lfloor{\dfrac{r}{2}}\right\rfloor,r\right].$$

Unsurprisingly, it also appears that in the limit as $n\to\infty$, the number of distinct digits in $n^2$ will almost surely be $r$.

Probably the best specific case to look at is when $r=4$. For the first $\sim 3\times 10^8$ valid $n$, I show the following counts for $n$ yielding each $k$:

$$
\begin{array}{|l|l|l|l|}
k & n\textrm{ count} & \max(f(n)) \\\hline
1 & 1 & 1_{4} \\\hline
2 & 4 & 2211_{4} \\\hline
3 & 591 & \infty \\\hline
4 & 316051761 & \infty
\end{array}
$$

$k=3$ terms seem to be growing very slowly and unpredictably.

Perhaps more relevant is $r=9$, which has the property that $k=5$ terms include every number of form $2^* \geq 222$, which I believe makes good sense from a quadratic residue point of view.

Comment: So your main question is whether only finite many numbers built only with the digits $1$ and $2$ have a square NOT containing all digits ?

Comment: That sounds correct.

Comment: The square of the $85$ digit number $$2221122121221212211112122112221222221121222222222211211111221111112112211111211111122$$ has no digit $5$. So, if there should be a largest such number , it will be extremely difficult to find it.

Comment: The square of the $45$ digit number $$212122221112121221122121222211211112221112212$$ has no digit $1$ and no digit $7$. Again, to find the largest such number (if there is a largest) will be extremely difficult.

Comment: The missing digits of the square of the $30$ digit number $$111122112211212121122111221222$$ are $5,6$ and $9$. But I guess this is far from optimal for $7$ distinct digits.

Comment: @Peter Thanks for the spot checks. And I agree; my suspicion is that the maximum number (if there is one) is maybe approaching something like double-exponential growth, but it's hard to tell. I'm reasonably sure that my $k=5$ value is the maximum, and I think the $k=6$ value is probably also tractable (I expect it's at $f(n) \leq 10^{25}$), but I doubt anything past that will be practical. This is why I'm hoping somebody might have an analytic insight as to which way this turns out.

Comment: $23$ digits seems to be challenging for $k=6$ , but this can easily be fully checked by brute force.

Comment: @Peter I did try every $f(n)$ up through $10^{24}$, and the interval between $[10^{23},10^{24}]$ was the first to have no cases of $k=6$ (I think there was only one in the order of magnitude before that), thus my suspicion that the maximum wouldn't be too far. (But that's also around where my program started becoming impractically slow, thus why I didn't double check.)

Comment: OK, I am approaching those ranges as well and with PARI/GP it is reasoanably fast. For $k=5$ , a larger example is in fact very unlikely.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141444/discussion-between-peter-and-trevor).

Comment: For $k=7$ , I found the sensational solution $$211111121111112111111211111121111112111112111111211111112111112111111211111112$$ with $78$ digits !

Comment: Not sure whether I understand the update correctly. But to prove that there are finite many numbers with digits $1,2$ such that the square in the decimal expansion is not pandigital will be very difficult , considering that there is a $140$ digit example with for which the square has no digit $3$ : $$22112212211122122112212122221222121111111121121212211212122221122122122221212121122212122111121111122221111212112111121212212221211222111121$$

Answer (score 5):

For your general question, we have the infinite sequences
$${\underbrace{33\ldots 33}_{n\text{ times}}}\,^2
={\underbrace{11\ldots 11}_{n-1\text{ times}}}\,0\,{\underbrace{88\ldots 88}_{n-1\text{ times}}}\,9$$
and
$${\underbrace{33\ldots 3}_{n-1\text{ times}}}\,4^2
={\underbrace{11\ldots 11}_{n\text{ times}}}\,{\underbrace{55\ldots 55}_{n-1\text{ times}}}\,6$$

Comment: Good point, I should have expected a straightforward counterexample... but this one also makes me wonder if the proof to this thing might be a matter of playing with quadratic residues—it's been a while since I've touched that area of math.

Comment: Also $33\ldots 32^2 = 11\ldots 11022\ldots 224$, 
$66\ldots 65^2 = 44\ldots 4422\ldots 22 5$, 
$66\ldots 66^2 = 44\ldots 44 3 55 \ldots 55 6$ and $66\ldots 67^2 = 44\ldots4488\ldots889$.